# Calling applet from a different directory

Tags: java, html, applet

So I'm running into a problem here getting an applet to run. The .class file is in another directory and I've learned that you can use the codebase attribute to point to where the file is. Here is my calling code.

```html
<applet codebase="/Cartographer/bin" code="CartographerApplet.class" width="300" height="150"></applet>
```

Now the .class file i'm looking for is in a package I've deemed Cartographer.

My question is, is there something I'm missing? Or is my code completely wrong? I have a hunch that I'm not doing the codebase part correctly because I don't really know how to provide a shortened path without giving the whole C:\ect\ect\ect path.

Edit: The root directory has the folder Cartographer in it which houses the java project for creating the app. So the path I have is what points to the .class file I need. I've tried using the code attribute with and without the Cartographer package attached to the beginning and I keep getting a class not found exception.

Comment: Show the structure of the server in terms of the location from the root to the HTML and the applet class.  BTW - if the package is `Cartographer`, the code attribute needs to be `Cartographer.CartographerApplet`..  Also: 1) Always copy/paste error or exception output. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: As in the path from the folder where index.html is correct? The root directory has the folder Cartographer in it which houses the java project for creating the app. So the path I have is what points to the .class file I need. I've tried using the code attribute with and without the Cartographer package attached to the beginning and I keep getting a class not found exception.

Edit: To answer your question, I couldn't really find a way to do what I wanted to do with just a combination of HTML, CSS, JQuery, and Javascript.

Comment: *"The root directory has.."* Edit the information into the question. *"I couldn't really find a way to do what I wanted to do with just a combination of HTML, CSS, JQuery, and Javascript."* My point is, base the app. around a `JFrame` and launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).   It will be less hassle for you, and a better experience for the end user.